# Remove extra spacing before and after a specific character within string

Tags: string, t-sql, trim

Is there a clean way to remove leading and trailing spaces from a specific character within a string. for example we have a name string and sometimes the name contains the husband and wife (e.g. Doe, John & Mary). However, sometimes when the name is entered the name gets fat fingered and extra spaces are included before and/or the after the & (e.g. '  &  ', '   & ', ' &   ', '   &   ','&  ', etc.).  Basically I just want to make sure anytime there is an & it is always one space before and one space after. I am sure there is an easy solution, but for some reason nothing I am trying (other than numerous replace(...)) seems to be working...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include tag for the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your programming language String.Trim() does exactly what you need.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netcore-3.1

edit: You can split the string into an array of strings then use trim on each element.

Answer (score 0):

A smart way would be to split your string into character, then add all your character into a dictionnary with key the character and value the position and rebuilt your string with this : you add the value to the key if existing value are not of distance one and key is a space " "

Answer (score 0):

I think this may solve your problem and also this may vary with languages.
In the case of Python,

```
name = "Doe &  John & Mary"
name = " & ".join(map(str.strip, name.split('&')))
```

In the case of JavaScript,

```
name = name.split('&').map(e => e.trim()).join(' & ');
```

This code snippet first splits the given word with the character '&' and strips (trim) each word at both the ends using map() and joins every word using " & ". 
#Happy Coding!